# Reference "this" element outside of a for-loop in JavaScript (JSLint)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, this, addeventlistener, jslint

Thank you in advance for your help!

I'm creating a simple tic-tac-toe game to help me learn native JavaScript, so my goal is to do as much as I can without jQuery or HTML/CSS for the game.

I am using a `for-loop` to create multiple `div` elements, adhering to JSLint. I am attaching an `.addEventListener()` as part of the process of creating my `div` elements to change the background color of **that specific** `div` when clicked.

I've been searching StackOverflow trying to use `this` to reference the specific `div` clicked. The only way I've been successful so far is by using an anonymous function *within* my `for-loop`. JSLint isn't impressed, and I get:

> Don't make functions within a loop.

When I try to call an external function and pass `this` in, the entire `div` creation process just stops working and I'm not sure why.

What I have (that "works"): https://jsfiddle.net/typj2LLb/4/

```js
// create game
var gameContainer = document.getElementById('board');
var createBoard = function() {
  'use strict';
  var index, square;
  for (index = 0; index < 9; index += 1) {
    square = document.createElement('div');
    square.className = 'tile';

    // tile event
    square.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    });

    gameContainer.appendChild(square);
  }
};

createBoard();
```

```css
.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25vh;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="board"></div>
</body>
```

What I think I'm supposed to be doing (that doesn't work): https://jsfiddle.net/e4mstyy9/1/

```js
// click-event
function changeColor(specificElement) {
  'use strict';
  specificElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}

// create game
var gameContainer = document.getElementById('board');
var createBoard = function() {
  'use strict';
  var index, square;
  for (index = 0; index < 9; index += 1) {
    square = document.createElement('div');
    square.className = 'tile';

    // tile event
    square.addEventListener('click', changeColor(this));

    gameContainer.appendChild(square);
  }
};

createBoard();
```

```css
.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25vh;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="board"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Always include the relevant or your code in your comment. You can even use stack snippets instead of jsfiddle to create inline runnable examples.

Comment: Ah, thank you Felix. I'll make sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice to not create functions inside a loop is only relevant if you are referencing the *loop variable* (or something derived from that variable) inside the function (see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196) for why).

But since you are not doing this, your code is perfectly fine and you can keep using it.

---

Why does the second example not work?

When you have an expression such as `foo(bar())`, `bar` will be called *first* and its *return value* will be passed to `foo`.

In your code you have `square.addEventListener('click', changeColor(this));`. That means `changeColor` is executed first and its return value is passed to `addEventListener`.

However, the engine isn't even getting that far because executing `changeColor(this)` throws the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

That's because the value you pass to `changeColor` (`this`) isn't a DOM element. Since you are using strict mode, the value of `this` is `undefined`, so you are executing `changeColor(undefined)`.

One way to solve this without creating a function inside the loop body would be to simply pass `changeColor` instead of calling it (which requires us to use `this` again):

```
// click-event
function changeColor() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}

// ...

square.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

This is actually a good change because the function is only created *once* and reused, instead of creating a new event handler for every element.

Comment: We could just have `function changeColor() { this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; }` and pass that like so: `square.addEventListener('click', changeColor));` https://jsfiddle.net/typj2LLb/7/

Comment: @lampyridae: Right, that makes more sense. I'll update the post.